# Need help combining the results of two select statements

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

My first select statements is:

```
SELECT cRefNum, cName,  cProgram || '-' || cCode || '-' || cSection as CourseDesc, cTimeStart, cTimeEnd, cDay, ct.cCampus, cBuildingSection || cRoom AS Room, cSchedType
from coursedetails cd inner join coursetimes ct
using (cRefNum)
where cRefNum = 3816;
```

Which results in:

[image: query 1 result]

My second select statements is:

```
select cRefNum, LISTAGG(fname|| ' ' || lname, ', ') within group (order by cRefNum) as Teachers
from teachers
where cRefNum = 3816
group by cRefNum;
```

Which results in:

[image: query 2 result]

What I'm trying to achieve is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.cRefNum, cName, CourseDesc, cTimeStart, cTimeEnd, cDay, Campus, Room, cSchedType, Teachers
from
(select cRefNum, cName,  cProgram || '-' || cCode || '-' || cSection as CourseDesc, cTimeStart, cTimeEnd, cDay, ct.cCampus as Campus, cBuildingSection || cRoom AS Room, cSchedType from coursedetails cd inner join coursetimes ct using (cRefNum) where cRefNum = 3816) a,
(select cRefNum, LISTAGG(fname|| ' ' || lname, ', ') within group (order by cRefNum) as Teachers from teachers where cRefNum = 3816 group by cRefNum) b
where a.cRefNum = b.cRefNum;
```

This fixes it, but is really long and I don't know enough to shorten it.